What is the <router-outlet> tag for in Angular?
I've already searched the documentation and blogs on the internet, but I can't clearly understand the purpose of the  tag. Could you explain the functionality of this tag to me by example?

After a quick research, I found an explanation in the official docs which I think cover all your points. What exactly are you missing? https://angular.dev/guide/routing/router-reference#router-outlet

@vinudev checkout this stackblitz and compare this with the docs link shared, it will give you clarity, if not please comment the actual doubt

A question about installing Angular CLI versions, whenever I install a new version, is it recommended to uninstall the old one and then install the new one after clearing the cache? Or do I just update the Angular CLI globally via ng update? This ended up causing me a lot of confusion, thanks in advance for the answer @Naren Murali

@vinudev when you upgrade it automatically upgrades the old version, after upgrading start the server, if any error occours, clear the cache, else leave it as it is.

When you have an Angular application that use "routes", each route indicate an angular component. in <router-outlet> is where the component is placed. This allow a component to have, e.g. a footer, a body with the <router-outlet> tag  and a header. Different routes "insert" the component inside the tag.

When I execute the following command  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }  am I performing an instantiation and injection of dependencies? Angular does this under the table, correct? @Naren murali

@vinudev yes, this is dependency injection, it is taken care of automatically by angular, but we need to add the import HttpClientModule(older angular versions) or provideHttpClient() in bootstrap application providers array (newer angular versions)

The <router-outlet> acts as a placeholder when dynamically loading components based on the current route. This enables multiple views to be displayed without reloading the entire page.
Example 
Let's say we have HomeComponent and AboutComponent. We can then define routes in app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

In app.component.html add the <router-outlet> tag
<h1>Angular App</h1>
<nav>
 <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
 <a routerLink="/about">About</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

When navigating between routes (i.e. Home and About), the component based on the current URL will be displayed in the router-outlet. It is a key part of Angular's routing mechanism that allows the creation of single-page applications (SPAs) meaning different views can be displayed without reloading the entire page when a user navigates to different routes.
